# How does it work when two riders are on one mount?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, prestige-class, mounted-combat

The prestige class [asavir](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/a-b/asavir/) gains at level 4 the supernatural ability **djinni’s blessing** that says

> When an asavir reaches 4th level, her mount receives the blessing of the djinn, making it swift and tireless. The mount’s speed increases by 10 feet, it doesn’t take movement penalties from wearing barding, and it **can carry a second rider without penalties.** When the asavir reaches 8th level, her mount’s speed increases by an additional 10 feet.

(Emphasis mine.) How is this handled? Are both creatures using the same saddle or does the mount need two saddles?

Are the riders adjacent or sharing the same space?

Further, can all three of mount and both riders make a charge? Can both riders benefit if one possesses the feat [Ride-by Attack](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/ride-by-attack-combat/)?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. I edited your question for clarity; I hope that's okay. Since mounted combat generally in *Pathfinder* is underdetailed, is an answer that also draws from *D&D 3.5* and homebrew material acceptable? Or would you prefer an explanation of *why* you should make up these rules? Also, although it's not required, it's useful to say that you're considering taking levels in the prestige class. (If you're just wondering, that's okay, too, but the site likes solving real problems instead of speculative ones.) Thank you for participating and have fun!

Comment: thanks for the editing, in fact, i search answer to pathfinder rules (but with all paizo document, faq .. accepted ;) )

Answer (score 1):

### How many saddles?

You'll have to ask your GM this one; the Djinni's Blessing is an exception to the rules and doesn't specify. It seems reasonable that you should have a second saddle (or more likely an [exotic](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipmenT/goods-and-services/animals-animal-gear/#Saddle) saddle that seats more than one person) or else the additional rider would suffer [bareback riding penalties](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/Ride/#Notes).

### Whose space is this anyway?

Per the [Mounted Combat](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Gamemastering/Combat/#Mounted_Combat) rules, all creatures on the mount would be considered sharing a space.

> For simplicity, assume that you share your mount’s space during combat.

There's no reason this would change with 3 targets. You are mounted on your steed, and your ally is mounted on your steed, so you and they are both sharing space with the steed.

### Charge! (and other combat stuff)

Since both of you are mounted, you both gain the penalties for the Charge action, and gain the benefits from a Charge if you make an attack at the end of the movement.

> If your mount charges, you also take the AC penalty associated with a charge. If you make an attack at the end of the charge, you receive the bonus gained from the charge.

Generally speaking, you won't share benefits from feats, but Ride-By-Attack is a bit of an exception... in part. Strictly by the book, the second rider could make their attack per Mounted Combat rules

> If your mount moves more than 5 feet, you can only make a single melee attack.

and the mount could continue its movement because the Asavir allows it. However, because they are not directly benefiting from the Feat, they could be subjected to attack(s) of opportunity.